# Iframe with session

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have to load an Iframe with a web page. I can load the web page successfully. I provide the src to iframe by applying the value to a constant from my javascript code in controller. Now I have to pass a session and username along with the url. How can I do that ?
In my controller, I have.

```
 $scope.URL = Constants.URL().myurl;
```

and in HTML, I have

```
<div id="FundMgt">
     <iframe id="myIFrame" src="{{URL |trusted}}" style="display: block;" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For browsers >= IE8, you can use `.postMessage`, [look at this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

If you won't use `.postMessage`, you can pass client argument with the hash `#` part of the url.

You can do `src="url?query#" + JSON.stringify({param1:"value1", param2:"value2"})`.

On the other side, you can retrieve the object with `var params = JSON.parse(window.location.hash)`.

I work on a library about this : [xssinterface](https://code.google.com/p/xssinterface/)

To retrieve a session, look into your cookies, the name is depending of your remote server (check with F12). [Cookie access in JS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: They are not the same domain.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can use `.postMessage`, `hash` or the `xssinterface` library.